# Combine multiple objects and create list of overlappng attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

I have a class like the following:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, A, B, C, D, E):
        self.ID = ID
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D
        self.E = E
```

And multiple objects in a list:

```
test1 = test(6124, 6, 'Tim', 'Football', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test2 = test(6124, 7, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test3 = test(6188, 8, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test4 = test(6188, 9, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test5 = test(6188, 10, 'Tim', 'Football', 'Soccer', 'USA')

objects_list = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]
```

I want to merge these objects based on their ID attribute and for the remaining attributes, just make a list of the individual objects:

For this example, the result would be two objects (as only two unique IDs), one of which would have attributes:

```
self.ID = 6124
self.A = [6, 7]
self.B = ['Tim', 'Joe']
self.C = ['Football', 'Basketball']
self.D = ['Soccer', 'Soccer']
self.E = ['USA', 'USA]
```

How can I merge the objects in the list in this way? I am looking for a solution which does not need me to name any attributes but the name of the   attribute on which I am merging (`ID`). It would be extra nice if this solution could be generalized to merge on multiple attributes at once (say `ID` and `A` and `E`).

Thanks!
Jack

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas` (i.e. a data manipulation library) ? That would be pretty straightforward

Comment: @RafaelC My actual use case is much more complex than this. This simple example was just to demonstrate the general idea in a reproducible manner.

Comment: You have a number of options. You could use a dictionary of lists where the key is the object ID and the lists are objects. You could implement a database to track object relationships. You could also change your object to store all non-ID attributes in lists. All you'd have to do would be adding a method similar to init that appends data to the lists: self.A.append(A). I think we may need more info on your use case.

Comment: @JackArnestad being more complex than this is just *one more argument* in favor of using a data manipulation library. You code will get big, messy and I'd say probably unmaintainable, where you can achieve what you want with one line of code using a library. But thats up to you, of course. I have posted one solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, A, B, C, D, E):
        self.ID = ID
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D
        self.E = E


test1 = Test(6124, 6, 'Tim', 'Football', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test2 = Test(6124, 7, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test3 = Test(6188, 8, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test4 = Test(6188, 9, 'Joe', 'Basketball', 'Soccer', 'USA')
test5 = Test(6188, 10, 'Tim', 'Football', 'Soccer', 'USA')

objects_list = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]

# get names of attributes except 'ID'
attrs = list(x for x in dir(test1) if not x.startswith('__') and x != 'ID')

# iterate through grouped by 'ID' elements
for id_, group in groupby(sorted(objects_list, key=attrgetter('ID')),
                          key=attrgetter('ID')):
    # create result object with lists as attributes
    result = Test(id_, *[[]]*len(attrs))

    # merge elements
    for x in group:
        for a in attrs:
            setattr(result, a, getattr(result, a) + [getattr(x, a)])

    print(result.ID, result.A, result.B, result.C, result.D, result.E)
```

Result:

```
6124 [6, 7] ['Tim', 'Joe'] ['Football', 'Basketball'] ['Soccer', 'Soccer'] ['USA', 'USA']
6188 [8, 9, 10] ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Tim'] ['Basketball', 'Basketball', 'Football'] ['Soccer', 'Soccer', 'Soccer'] ['USA', 'USA', 'USA']
```